# Accounting for rounding when using arithmetic series

Tags: calculus

I am working on a problem where a list of numbers have to be summed. This list is the consecutive multiples of $\pi$ starting with $1\pi$ and finishing with $n\pi$. For example the list might be

> $\pi$, $2\pi$, $3\pi$, $4\pi$, $5\pi$

So $1\pi + 2\pi + 3\pi + 4\pi + 5\pi =  15\pi$

Then there is the problem of what is $n=100$

Well you can just use the formula used to sum an arithmetic series.

$$S=\frac{100(2\pi+\pi(100-1))}{2}$$

However, the problem with this is a number in the list is always rounded down before it is summed. This is a problem when just adding it as the list becomes

> 3, 6, 9, 12, 15

So $3 + 6+9+12+15=45$ whereas $15\pi \approx 47.124$

The problem is that this method would take a long time for longer lists consisting of 100 or more terms.

My question is how could you account for this in the arithmetic formula so that it returns the value after each number has been rounded down?

Comment: Getting an exact formula in this situation is very difficult, perhaps hopeless. There are some ways to get approximate formulas, although they involve some advanced mathematics (analysis). The general expectation should be that rounding down loses you $\frac12$ per term on average.